# Certificates being renewed yearly - how to reliably find them in the cert store?

Tags: certificate, x509certificate

I've been tasked to add security by means of certificates to an external web service we call from our ASP.NET 4.0 Webforms application.

I've been able to play around with the certificate and get the code to work properly, but there are still a lot of questions unanswered when it comes to deployment of that solution. I'm pretty new to actually *using* (and dealing with) certificates - I understand the basic theory behind them, just never used them much myself.

The service is an external REST webservice provided by a company which also issues the certificates - and those will expire on a yearly basis and need to be renewed yearly. So "baking" them into the ASP.NET app as an internal resource doesn't seem like a good idea.

I'm leaning towards putting them into the certificate store on the Windows 2008 Server. That works fine, but what I'm not sure about: how do I *FIND* the appropriate certificate from code? I know about the `X509Certificate2` and `X509Store` classes - but what **criteria** should I search for?

What item (Serial number? Thumbprint?) would remain the same if that cert has to be renewed every year? Or do I have to update my config and store a new serial number or thumbprint every time the cert has been renewed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you need to ensure that you are communicating with correct web service.

You are using https to connect to the REST service. Is it a WCF service or Web API? Either way the web server will handle the SSL part (hmm, only if hosted on a web server and not self hosted). So if we make it easy then the web service is hosted on a web server. The web server will handle establishing SSL connection and will send you server certificate.

Then you need to check if you are communicating with correct web server. Your options are:

1. manually update config file with thumbprint that will change every time the certificate of web server will be renewed. Also serial number will change when they renew the certificate.
2. check for common name in the subject or better if the is correct DNS name (of the web server) in Subject alternative name (SAN = extension in the certificate) or in CN (when SAN is not in the certificate)
3. build a certificate chain (using [X509Chain.Build](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509chain.build%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method) from web server's certificate and check if it contains a CA certificate that you have embedded in ASP.NET application or if it matches given thumbprint of CA from you config.

1) - will work but you have to ensure to update config file every year

2) - will work nice until they change DNS name of the web server, but it would result in change of your web.config so ... it will work. One thing to note is that extracting any extension from X509Certificate2 class using standard .NET framework is not easy. You would need to either go to ASN.1 level or use some crypto library that can extract the SAN in a friendly way.

3) - will work nicely. You can use Root CA certificate or dedicated intermediate CA certificate. You have to ensure that web server certificate is trusted for certificate chain to be built but that applies generally to all solutions. It will work pretty long time because CA certificates are issued to i.e. 20-30 years.

Comment: So there's *nothing* in the certificate that **stays the same** over time, when it is being renewed? Something like a "certificate GUID" or something.... something I can use to find that certificate at all times, no matter how many times it's been renewed in the mean time??

Comment: Common name and Subject alternative name. These will stay the same because there will the DNS name of the server stored. And when the DNS name should change you will have to update links in you web.config so changing one more configuration property is nothing. Issuer should stay the same too, but they might issue the next certificate with different CA and because it is not in your hands you can't rely on that.